# InstantiationError: org.quartz.JobDetail makes tomcat9 start failed in linux but fine in windows

Tags: java, linux, spring, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I have a restful api application developed on spring 4 and runs in tomcat 7(with jdk8) 
Now I tried to deploy it to tomcat 9(build&run with jdk8), the war file built without any issue. But the tomcat 9 in linux failed to start, the error is:

> 17:44:02:821 WARN [XmlWebApplicationContext] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ediFeedTask' defined in class path resource [spring-scheduler.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationError: org.quartz.JobDetail
>   17:44:02:839 ERROR [ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ediFeedTask' defined in class path resource [spring-scheduler.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationError: org.quartz.JobDetail
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]

Basically it failed to instantiate the bean defined in spring quartz xml. Because if I comment out all the beans definition in my spring-scheduler.xml, the application start successfully. The beans are all scheduled jobs.

But I don't get why tomcat9 got problem instantiate bean for quartz scheduler. It instantiate beans in other xmls well, like api-config.xml or spring-controller.xml.

The most weird thing is, the same war file deployed and start successfully in windows tomcat 9, just failed in tomcat 8 and 9 in linux (ubuntu, deepin), does anyone have any clue?

Below is my spring-scheduler.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="ediFeedJob" class="com.ai.api.job.EDIFeedJob" />
    <bean id="ediFeedTask"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
        <property name="targetObject" ref="ediFeedJob" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="execute" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="ediFeedCronTrigger"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="ediFeedTask" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 2 * * * ?"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="startQuartz" lazy-init="false"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                 <ref bean="ediFeedCronTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is a maven dependency issue. It's not apparent as "XXX class not found" as we usually see, but in this case it's complaining "InstantiationError: org.quartz.JobDetail" -- so we can assume something wrong with spring itself.

After checking the conflicts in maven dependency I can see spring-beans 2.0.3 is referenced, while normally it should be at least newer than 4.0. So just exclude it

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-modules-jakarta-commons</artifactId>
<version>${spring.modules.jakarta.commons.version}</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

then problem solved.